# Disable physical left click on touchpad but keeping tap

Tags: touchpad, libinput

I need to disable the clicking on touchpad as my touchpad is a bit broken and get stuck specifically on the left side. Unfortunately I am unable to find the one-line command.

Comment: You can achieve that by using `xinput list` and then setting the right parameter on `xinput float $id`. You can find a better explanation on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/178741/1153225).

Comment: Thanks that drills down a lot the search. I'm trying to find the correct command, can you further help? It should be 'Click Method Enabled' but disabling doesn't really help

Comment: You need to see the id of the touchpad when you use the command `xinput list`. In my case it's named `ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad` and its id is 14. So I can deactivate the touchpad by executing `xinput float 14`. You have to check which id the right id for you...

Comment: I found the ID of the touchpad but I didn't find the exact function "clicking". I don't want to deactivate the whole touchpad just the function concerning the click. Like i need the tap-to-click or drag-drop functions